# postgres: Check pair of columns when inserting new row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | person | supporter | referredby|
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
0   | ABC    | DEF       |           |
1   | ABC    | GHI       | DEF       |
2   | CBA    | FED       |           |
3   | CBA    | IHG       | FED       |
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is I'd like postgres to reject an INSERT if the value in `referredby` isn't in the `supporter` column for a specific person. (null `referredby` is ok)

For example, with the data above:

- `4, 'ABC', 'JKL', null`: accepted (can be null)
- `4, 'ABC', 'JKL', 'IHG'`: rejected (IHG not listed as a supporter for ABC)
- `4, 'ABC', 'JKL', 'DEF'`: accepted (DEF is listed as a supporter for ABC)

Maybe a check constraint? I'm not sure how to piece it together

Comment: A foreign key perhaps?

Comment: Would that work for checking two columns? I thought it was limited to one only

Comment: You need a unique constraint on (person, supporter), then add a fk.

Comment: Ah! Lovely -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a foreign key that references person, supporter. (Needs to be unique key.)

```
alter table t add constraint cname unique(person, supporter);

alter table t add constraint fk foreign key (person, referredby)
    references t (person, supporter);
```

(ANSI SQL syntax, but probably also supported by Postgresql.)